# Grid Row Freezing

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin23

Is there a way to freeze the top-most row in a Vaadin Grid so that it can always be viewed, no matter how much the user scrolls vertically? I was looking at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/#column-freezing, but I'm not sure if this would help for rows.

Comment: Make it a table header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on idea given in the commments, here is a proof of concept code that demonstrate how to do it Vaadin Grid.

```
    Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();
    grid.setHeight("250px");
    grid.setWidth("250px");
    GridListDataView<String> dataView = grid.setItems("Zero","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten");
    Column<String> col = grid.addColumn(value -> value.toString()).setHeader("A number");
    HeaderRow row = grid.appendHeaderRow();
    Div div = new Div();
    div.setText(dataView.getItem(0).toString());
    div.getElement().getStyle().set("text-align", "left");
    div.getElement().getStyle().set("width", "100%");
    row.getCell(col).setComponent(div);                
    grid.addSelectionListener(event -> {
        event.getFirstSelectedItem().ifPresent(item -> {
            div.setText(item.toString());                
        });
    });
```